# solr local parameters not recognized

Tags: solr

I would like to use parameter dereferencing as explain here:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/local-parameters-in-queries.html

The example for using local parameters does not work for me, the local parameters are parsed as input query text:

My query:

```
/solr/core/select?q={!dismax%20qf=name}blabla&debugQuery=true
```

The parsed query info gives me:

```
"rawquerystring": "{!dismax qf=name}blabla",
"querystring": "{!dismax qf=name}blabla",
"parsedquery": "+(DisjunctionMaxQuery(((name:dismax)^5.0 | description:dismax)) 
   DisjunctionMaxQuery(((name:qf)^5.0 | description:qf)) DisjunctionMaxQuery(((name:name)^5.0 | 
   description:name)) DisjunctionMaxQuery(((name:blabla)^5.0 | description:blabla)))~4",
"parsedquery_toString": "+((((name:dismax)^5.0 | description:dismax) ((name:qf)^5.0 | 
   description:qf) ((name:name)^5.0 | description:name) ((name:blabla)^5.0 | 
   description:blabla))~4)",
"explain": {},
...
```

I use `edismax` as default query parser and my default `qf` is `name^5 description`

I tried with other query parsers and always the same happens. Any idea?

Comment: You might need to check `select` requestHandler definition in solrconfig.xml. Also, you can try to set which query parser to use using `defType` parameter, eg `solr/core/select?q=blabla&defType=dismax&qf=name&debugQuery=true`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EricLavault.  Actually I am currently using the parameters as you suggest. It woks as expected. But I wanted to use this local params feature to implement a slightly more complex query. However, the simplest local param example of the user guide does not  work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use localparams directly in `q` with `edismax` set as your parser. The `edismax` query parser [does not support this since 7.2](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/local-q-op-AND-ignored-for-edismax-query-tp4405501p4405504.html).

> Since 7.2, you can only use certain localparams if defType is lucene or
>   func.  The lucene parser is the default.  Since you have changed defType
>   to edismax, localparams will not work.

I'm not sure why you'd need the localparams in your example anyway, since you can add `qf=name` directly to your URL?